# How can I find parent pom.xml location scan the project with Fortify SCA?

Tags: java, maven, command, pom.xml, fortify

I'm working on multi module maven projects and I'm trying scan this project with Fortify SCA. Sometimes no parent pom.xml in the project directory and Fortify throws an error because it can't find the pom.

Sometimes there is no parent pom in the main directory of the project. It can be in internal folders. Fortify also gives an error because it cannot find the pom when trying to process in the home directory.

So I have to somehow find the parent pom.xml path and give it to fortify to scan.

I am using command line in background so I need to find the pom path or if there is a translate option in Fortify I need to add it.

Thanks for help.